# How to detect day change in Swift

Tags: swift, observers

I want my app to act when there is a change to another day.

So, in my appDelegate, I put

```
func applicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication){
        //this one fires
    }
```

and in the ViewController that should update its content I do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.dayChanged(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("significantTimeChangeNotification"), object: nil)

    }
```

and

```
@objc func dayChanged(notification: NSNotification){
        //this one doesn't fire
    }
```

somehow, while the func in AppDelegate is called, the observer seems to be blind for that event.

Is this syntax, or just plain misunderstanding of the mechanism?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add an observer for `"UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification"`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dayChanged), name: UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

For **Swift 4.2 or later**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dayChanged), name: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

---

Note: If your intent is to be notified when the day changes you can use `.NSCalendarDayChanged` (`"NSCalendarDayChangedNotification"`) instead of `UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dayChanged), name: .NSCalendarDayChanged, object: nil)
```

---

And add the selector method to the view controller where you would like to monitor the day changes:

```
@objc func dayChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
    
}
```

Comment: @Sjakelien note that you might want `.NSCalendarDayChanged` instead of `UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification`

Comment: Good point. I will try.
Also, apparently the AppDelegate part is not necessary at all

Comment: Yes usually you don't need to use the AppDelegate method. The correct approach is to add an observer and implement an instance method in your view controller.