# How to check the date everyday in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to the swiftUI. Right now, I am making an app that takes down your task progress. In the app, I need to refill the list with goals of user have every day (I guess 12 AM), where and how do I check the time in swift? I know that we could use app delegate in storyboard, but for SwiftUI, after applying CoreData Manager, the app delegate has gone and we have app.swift instead, where should I do the checking now? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application;` in AppDelegate to monitor such changes.
2. You can also register for a notification in AppDelegate `UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification`
   iOS will call both the registered notification method as well above delegate method.

```
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(timeChanged), name: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification , object: nil)
```

```
 @objc func timeChanged() {
        print("App Time Changed")
    }
```

3. In case you want to hook up with your SwiftUI directly, you can register your Swift view with your publisher.
   Publisher will listen for notification name `UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification`.

Either of the ways can be used based on your requirement.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dayDetails: String = "Hello World"
    var body: some View {
        Text(dayDetails)
            .padding().onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification), perform: { _ in
                dayDetails = "Day has changed"
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a `NSCalendarDayChanged` notification exactly for this purpose. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1408062-nscalendardaychanged and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021758/2303865

Answer (score 4):

Building off of Leo Dabus' suggestion to watch for `NSCalendarDayChanged` notifications here's some code showing how that can be done in SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.displayDate)
            // List of goals
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentDate: Date = Date()

    var displayDate: String {
        Self.simpleDateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
    }

    private static let simpleDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d"
        return formatter
    }()

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dayDidChange), name: .NSCalendarDayChanged, object: nil)
    }

    @objc
    func dayDidChange() {
        currentDate = Date()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using @kardaj answer (which is 99% correct) I got the alert:

> make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates

To resolve this annoying issue (in fact there is a reason we get this) I added the following:

> .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main))

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged).receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)) { _ in
     // do what you want as soon as the day changes (23:59:59 --> 00:00:00)
}
```

That solved the issue.

Comment: This is the solution! Worked perfectly for my macOS menu bar app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NSCalendarDayChanged` notification to execute some code when the day changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var text: String = "Hello World"
var body: some View {
    Text(text)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged)) { _ in
            text = "Day has changed"
        })
    }
}
```