# Update variables when day changes Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I think I will have a bug in my iOS app
I'm currently building a class that'll allow me to fetch data from user's calendar, but I realized I might have a bug if the user leaves the app without closing it, and then comes back after making changes in his calendar events, my app won't take them into consideration.

For now I'm at the very beginning of the class (still relatively new in OOP) but I think I'll encounter the same problem with only this bit of code (if he leaves the app at 11:45pm and then comes back at 1:00am the day will not be updated I guess ?)

EDIT: Sorry if I was unclear, what I mean by the day won't be updated is that if write this in my ContentView

```swift
let cal = CalendarManager()
```

The values of cal.weekday, cal.day etc won't be updated since the initialization has already been done (and the app not closed). I could easily write an update function but I need a way to detect when the user reopens the app.

So I'm looking for a solution to this, thanks a lot if someone can help (excuse my English I'm French =D)

Here's the class

```swift
/// This class will contain all the methods used to fetch data (next event, last event of day etc) from user's calendar
class CalendarManager {
    public var weekdayNb: Int
    public var weekday: String
    
    public var day: String
    
    public var monthNb: Int
    public var month: String
    public var year: String
    
    private let weekDays = [
        "Dimanche",
        "Lundi",
        "Mardi",
        "Mercredi",
        "Jeudi",
        "Vendredi",
        "Samedi"
    ]
    private let months = [
        "Janvier",
        "Février",
        "Mars",
        "Avril",
        "Mai",
        "Juin",
        "Juillet",
        "Août",
        "Septembre",
        "Octobre",
        "Novembre",
        "Décembre"
    ]
    
    init() {
        let date = Date()
        self.weekdayNb = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date) - 1
        self.weekday = weekDays[weekdayNb]
        self.day = String(Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date))
        self.monthNb = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
        self.month = months[monthNb - 1]
        self.year = String(Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date))
    }
}
```

Comment: “ the day will not be updated”, what day is that? Your question is quite unclear and we can’t really help you with so little information.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, for exemple if I use
`let calendar = CalendarManager()`
in my ContentView, I guess the data will not be updated if the user doesn't close the app (init won't be called anymore since it has been initialized).
I'd like to find a way to detect that the user has come back into the app
(I'll modify the post for others, sorry again)

Comment: What you need is to add an observer for day changed notification https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021758/2303865

Comment: You can use the notification manager to subscribe to `NSCalendarDayChanged` notifications. You'd pass the notification manager the selector of a method in your class that you would like to be called when the calendar day changes. You could then update your UI as needed.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answers I'll look into it =D
How can I mark the post as solved (sorry I'm not really used to StackOverflow ^^) ?
Thanks again

Comment: No need to take any action. Happy to help. If you need any further help let us know.